# Error in Insert into database in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a problem with this code :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [arch].[spInsertToDocumentFileCategoryRelation]
        @DocumentNumber nvarchar(50)
       ,@DocumentDate date
       ,@IsDocumentDelete bit
       ,@Address nvarchar(max)
       ,@DocumentLevelTypeId int

       ,@DocumentId2 bigint
       ,@DocumentRelationTypeId tinyint

       ,@CategoryId bigint 
       ,@FileId bigint

       ,@FileAssignCategoryId bigint OUTPUT
       ,@DocumentRelationId bigint OUTPUT
       ,@FileOfDocumentId bigint OUTPUT
       ,@DocumentId bigint OUTPUT

AS
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO [arch].[Document]
       (
        [DocumentNumber]
       ,[DocumentDate]
       ,[DateOfDocumentCreate]
       ,[IsDocumentDelete]
       ,[Address]
       ,[DocumentLevelTypeId]
       )
    VALUES
       (
        @DocumentNumber
       ,@DocumentDate
       ,'2015-5-12'
       ,@IsDocumentDelete
       ,@Address
       ,@DocumentLevelTypeId
       )

       Set @DocumentId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

       INSERT INTO [arch].[FileOfDocument]
       (
       [DocumentId]
       ,[FileId]
       )
    VALUES
       (
       @DocumentId
       ,@FileId
       )

       Set @FileOFDocumentId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

       INSERT INTO [arch].[DocumentRelation]
       (
        [DocumentRelationTypeId]
        ,[DocumentId1]
        ,[DocumentId2]

       )
    VALUES
       (
        @DocumentRelationTypeId
       ,@DocumentId
       ,@DocumentId2
       )

       Set @DocumentRelationId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

       INSERT INTO [arch].[FileAssignCategory]
       (
        [CategoryId]
       ,[FileId]
       )
    VALUES
       (
        @CategoryId
       ,@FileId
       )

       Set @FileAssignCategoryId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
END
```

this code Execute correctly but when I want to test this Stored Procedure with some input values, sql server report some errors :

```
Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Procedure     
spInsertToDocumentFileCategoryRelation, Line 27
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'DocumentTypeId', table    
'ffisherDB.arch.Document'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

The statement has been terminated.
Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Procedure    
spInsertToDocumentFileCategoryRelation, Line 48 
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'DocumentId', table 
'ffisherDB.arch.FileOfDocument'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.
Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Procedure   
spInsertToDocumentFileCategoryRelation, Line 61
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'DocumentId1', table 
'ffisherDB.arch.DocumentRelation'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT    
fails.
The statement has been terminated.

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)
```

I have four Key that set with SCOPE_IDENTITY(). the first one set exactly right but the others fails and above Errors report.

please help me.

Comment: `Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'DocumentTypeId', table    
'ffisherDB.arch.Document'; column does not allow nulls.`   Says it all.

Answer (score 0):

Well, from error text it looks like your `arch.Document` table has non-nullable column `DocumentTypeId`.

And you're not filling that column here:

```
INSERT INTO [arch].[Document]
   (
    [DocumentNumber]
   ,[DocumentDate]
   ,[DateOfDocumentCreate]
   ,[IsDocumentDelete]
   ,[Address]
   ,[DocumentLevelTypeId]
   )
```

So this column has its default value (I guess it is null), thus this insert fails, thus `@DocumentId` is null and remaining inserts fails too...

Answer (score 0):

As per first error message `DocumentTypeId` field in `Document` table is not allowing null. You should insert a value into it in the insert query.

Change your insert to

```
INSERT INTO [arch].[Document]
       (
        [DocumentNumber]
       ,[DocumentDate]
       ,[DateOfDocumentCreate]
       ,[IsDocumentDelete]
       ,[Address]
       ,[DocumentLevelTypeId]
       ,[DocumentTypeId]  --Add document type id here
       )
    VALUES
       (
        @DocumentNumber
       ,@DocumentDate
       ,'2015-5-12'      --You better insert a DATE type or in ISO formatted 'yyyymmdd' string. 
       ,@IsDocumentDelete
       ,@Address
       ,@DocumentLevelTypeId
       ,@DocumentTypeId  --Insert a non - null value 
       )
```

Second & third error messages are due to first error.